# Is this a CompletableFuture chaining anti-pattern?

Tags: java, completable-future

Lately I have been applying a pattern where I chain futures together where for some future I don't care about the result but I do care it completed without exception before continuing the futures chain.

What I do is using *thenCompose()* and then supply it with a CompletableFuture that always ends with *.thenApply(a)*. Example:

```java
futureR
   .thenCompose(r -> sequentialFutureTask1(r).thenApply(ignored -> r))
   .thenCompose(r -> sequentialFutureTask2(r).thenApply(ignored -> r))
   .thenCompose(r -> sequentialFutureTask3(r).thenApply(ignored -> r))
```

I've even streamlined this with a helper method:

```java
futureFoo
   .thenCompose(identityComposing(r -> sequentialFutureTask1(r)))
   .thenCompose(identityComposing(r -> sequentialFutureTask2(r)))
   .thenCompose(identityComposing(r -> sequentialFutureTask3(r)))



public static <T> Function<T, CompletableFuture<T>> identityComposing(Function<T, CompletableFuture<?>> c) {
    return r -> cf.apply(r).thenApply(ignored -> r);
}
```

Is this an anti-pattern? It looks concise enough to me, but somehow I feel I missed some point.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve through the trailing `thenApply`. `thenCompose` alone already fails early. Maybe add some runnable code showing expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: The trailing thenApply is there to continue the return type of the previous stage. Like Stream.peek()

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that case.

Comment: In reactive programming paradigm it would be considered an anti-pattern because your processors produces unknown side effects instead of getting input and returning value down the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the invisible side-effects pointed out by [Antoniossss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527544/antoniossss) in the comments, which drives this a bit away from functional programming, the other issue is that you are still repeating yourself with all these `identityComposing()` wrapping calls.

As you said, the requirement is that those methods are called in sequence, so semantically you don’t really need the "composition" result. The intent is really to chain the calls themselves.

This would be best represented by composing those calls directly instead:

```
futureR.thenAccept(r -> sequentialFutureTask1(r)
           .thenCompose(ignored -> sequentialFutureTask2(r))
           .thenCompose(ignored -> sequentialFutureTask3(r)));
```

Of course, there is still a lot of repetition here with the `thenCompose(ignored -> …(r))`. If this is a frequent pattern you have, you could wrap this in the following method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public final <R> void executeInSequence(R r,
        Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>> firstTask,
        Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>>... otherTasks) {
    CompletionStage<?> prev = firstTask.apply(r);
    for (Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>> task : otherTasks) {
        prev = prev.thenCompose(ignored -> task.apply(r));
    }
}
```

<sub>(I also wanted to do this with `Stream` but I didn’t find a nice, clean solution)</sub>

which you would use as:

```
futureR.thenAccept(r -> executeInSequence(r,
        this::sequentialFutureTask1,
        this::sequentialFutureTask2,
        this::sequentialFutureTask3));
```

or if you prefer to pass `futureR` as parameter:

```
@SafeVarargs
public final <R> void executeAfter(CompletionStage<R> futureR,
        Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>> firstTask,
        Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>>... otherTasks) {
    futureR.thenAccept(r -> {
        CompletionStage<?> prev = firstTask.apply(r);
        for (Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>> task : otherTasks) {
            prev = prev.thenCompose(ignored -> task.apply(r));
        }
    });
}
```

used as:

```
executeAfter(futureR,
        this::sequentialFutureTask1,
        this::sequentialFutureTask2,
        this::sequentialFutureTask3);
```

Alternatively, this `executeAfter()` can be implemented with one less parameter:

```
@SafeVarargs
public final <R> void executeAfter2(CompletionStage<R> futureR,
        Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>>... otherTasks) {
    futureR.thenAccept(r -> {
        CompletionStage<?> prev = futureR;
        for (Function<? super R, ? extends CompletionStage<?>> task : otherTasks) {
            prev = prev.thenCompose(ignored -> task.apply(r));
        }
    });
}
```

but this `prev = futureR` causes an additional, useless `thenCompose()` that might be confusing (performance impact should be negligible since `futureR` is already completed when this will be invoked).